# Write an excel formula all column with python

Tags: python, excel, formula

I have existing excel document and want to update M column according to A column. And I want to start from second row to maintain first row 'header'.

Here is my code;

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/formula.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']

for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['M'], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=_xlfn.ISOWEEKNUM(A2)'.format(i)

wb.save('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/formula.xlsx')
```

When I run that code;

-first row 'header' changes.

-all columns in excel "ISOWEEKNUM(A2)", but I want it to change according to row number (A3,A4,A5... "ISOWEEKNUM(A3), ISOWEEKNUM(A4), ISOWEEKNUM(A5)....")

[image]

Edit:

I handled right now the ISOWEEKNUM issue with below code. I changed A2 to A2:A5.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/formula.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']

for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['M'], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=_xlfn.ISOWEEKNUM(A2:A5)'.format(i)

wb.save('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/formula.xlsx')
```

But still starts from first row.

Comment: Careful: it seems like your current code does not populate the column 'M' the way you want! The week number currently does not get updated based on the date in column 'A'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using `pandas`.

Let us consider the following spreadsheet:

[image]

First import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then load the third sheet of your excel workbook into a dataframe called `df`:

```
df=pd.read_excel('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/formula.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Update column 'column_to_update' using column 'deneme'. The line below converts the dates in the 'deneme' column from strings to datetime objects and then returns the week of the year associated with each of those dates.

```
df['Column_to_update'] = pd.to_datetime(df['deneme']).dt.week
```

You can then save your dataframe to a new excel document:

`df.to_excel('./newspreadsheet.xlsx', index=False)`

Here is the result:

[image]

You can see that the values in 'column_to_update' got updated from 1, 2 and 3 to 12, 12 and 18.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to create a new column. I want to update a existing column.

Comment: The exact same syntax will allow you to either create a new column or update an existing column. Please check my edited answer above.